# So how to print condition specific result on view in case the second block has nested db queries in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have this existing snippet on custom php.. I am trying to check whether there are existing painting details in the db.. if painting details r found i need to get details of the latest added ones upto count 6 & print detail accordingly. Here is my code->

```
<?php
    $pData=mysql_query("select * from painting_data");
    if($pData === FALSE) { 
        echo "<div class='well'>No painting available.</div>";
    }
    else{
        $pDet=mysql_query("Select * from painting_data order by padd desc limit 6");
        while($pD=mysql_fetch_assoc($pDet)){
            $pId=$pD['pid'];
            $pTitle=$pD['ptitle'];
            $pImg=$pD['pimg'];
?>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 img-recent-container">
    <img role="button" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive img-recent" onclick="location.href='?p=<?php echo $pId; ?>'" src="..<?php echo $pImg;?>" alt="<?php echo $pTitle;?>"/>
</div>  
<?php   }
    } ?>
```

Now I am new to CI.. & i am confused on how to separate the data retrieval properly. Since the else block has a query in it as well.. I am confused how not to include it in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with DB data in model only and pass returned results to controller. It is MVC paradigm.

P_m.php (model)

```
P_m extends CI_Model
{
    public $return = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();//or load it in APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'
    }

    public function p()
    {
        $q = $this->db->query("select * from painting_data");
        $return['error'] = $q->num_rows() > 0 ? FALSE : TRUE;

        $q->free_result();

        if ($return['error'] === FALSE)
        {
            $q = $this->db->query("Select * from painting_data order by padd desc limit 6");
            $this->return = $q->result();
        }

        return $return;
    }
}
```

P_c.php (controller):

```
P_c extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('p_m');//if used more often, load it in APPPATH . 'config/config.php'
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $output_data['data_from_p_m'] = $this->p_m->p();
        $this->load->view('p_v', $output_data);
    }
}
```

p_v.php (view):

```
if ( $data_from_p_m['error'] === FALSE ) 
{
    var_dump($data_from_p_m);
}
else
{
    echo "<div class='well'>No painting available.</div>";
}
```

You have to declare array before while loop to be able to get all 6 `$pId`, `$ptitle` and `$pimg`.

Comment: thanx ur response.. it's the one that helped me on my final code.. though ur code returned array with only the error value. i checked. what was happening is that "$this->return = $q->result()" was not adding the query result with the existing error boolean value in the return array. so i modded it a bit

Comment: Cool. It was just from head to leave you idea. You tested it though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing db queries in the view, is it ?

Application flow should be like this : controller -> model -> controller -> view

The controller is where user lands when they access your website url. The controller calls model, the model process the database and returns the result back to the controller (I prefer to fetch the data from db and populate an array then return that array to the controller), the controller then loads the view and supplies the array along with it. The view simply go over the array, preferably in a loop and create the html. There also need to be some system in case there was no record in the db or if there was an error.

**Sample code :**

```
Controller :

class Mypage extends CI_Controller {

public function index (  )
{
    $this->load->model ( 'Mypage _model' );

    $data['dbdata'] = $this->mypage_model->get ();

    /** Check Errors */
    if ( $data['dbdata'] === FALSE ) { //show 404 or something else }

    $data[ 'title' ] = 'my Page';

    $this->load->view ( 'mypage', $data);
}

}


Model :

class Login_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->error ['error'] = TRUE;
}

public function get (  )
{
    $data = array ();

    /** Get your database records here.*/
    if ( $some_error_condition ) return FALSE;

    if ( $no_records_found ) return $this->error;

    return $data;
}

}

View :

if ( isSet( $error ) ) // no records found.
{
   //do something
}
else {
   foreach ( $dbdata as $key => $value )
   {
       //do something
   }
}
```